# What are mux files extrated from KEYENCE VT5-X10 HMI to USB or how can I open those mux files?

Tags: plc, ladder-logic

Those mux files I got them from HMI KEYENCE VT5-X10 to my USB and it suppose that were screen's data. I tried to open them with VT Studio expecting to get screens desing but it was unsuccess. I expect to know what are those files and what I can do with those files.